# Error importing gradle project with Android studio

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio, gradle

I've a problem importing a gradle project with Android Studio. I select the folder of my application and then choose "Import project for external_model" When i click next, i've an error fired in my console. That's the trace:

```
ERROR - com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue - Error during dispatching of java.awt.event.MouseEvent[MOUSE_RELEASED,(1084,751),absolute(1685,1041),button=1,modifiers=Button1,clickCount=1] on dialog0 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: @NotNull method com/intellij/openapi/externalSystem/model/settings/LocationSettingType.getColor must not return null
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.settings.LocationSettingType.getColor(LocationSettingType.java:54)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.settings.GradleProjectSettingsControl.deduceGradleHomeIfPossible(GradleProjectSettingsControl.java:279)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.settings.GradleProjectSettingsControl.resetExtraSettings(GradleProjectSettingsControl.java:236)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.settings.AbstractExternalProjectSettingsControl.reset(AbstractExternalProjectSettingsControl.java:65)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.settings.AbstractImportFromExternalSystemControl.reset(AbstractImportFromExternalSystemControl.java:153)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.wizard.AbstractExternalProjectImportBuilder.prepare(AbstractExternalProjectImportBuilder.java:107)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.wizard.SelectExternalProjectStepBase.initGradleSettingsControl(SelectExternalProjectStepBase.java:90)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.wizard.SelectExternalProjectStepBase.updateStep(SelectExternalProjectStepBase.java:44)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.newProjectWizard.AddModuleWizard.updateStep(AddModuleWizard.java:172)
    at com.intellij.ide.wizard.AbstractWizard.doNextAction(AbstractWizard.java:377)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.newProjectWizard.AddModuleWizard.doNextAction(AddModuleWizard.java:241)
    at com.intellij.ide.wizard.AbstractWizard$5.actionPerformed(AbstractWizard.java:197)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
```

I've tried to reinstall Android Studio, update it (0.1.1, 0.1.7, 0.1.8 versions)and always the same error.
I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS  and my JDK version is 1.6.0_26
I've also tried to install gradle 1.6 and add bin folder to my path, but it doesn't work.

Comment: i'm having same issue. did you resoled it?